# Check to see if box fits in another box

Tags: math, dimensions, bounding

Given LxWxH of a box A, and LxWxH of a box B, how can I do a simple check to see if A fits in B (with 90 degrees rotations if necessary)?  I'm trying to avoid checking all the possible permutations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I would check to see if

```
minimum dimension of A < minimum dimension of B &&
median dimension of A < median dimension of B  &&
maximum dimension of A < maximum dimension of B
```

If those 3 conditions are met, A fits in B.

Comment: The comparison would be <= so boxes with equal dims are not dismissed. This is assuming that we are comparing the internal dims of B and the external dims of A. In real life we have to account for the thickness of the material the boxes are made with.